# fetch data from db and display in dropdown

Tags: php

Would like to fetch the details from table and display in dropdown but below code displays only dropdown without any data.not sure whats worng.

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = "select name from finance";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<select name='name'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

can some please advice.

Comment: R u getting any record? hope there is no db connection problem? try to use mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: You have checked number of rows return by query

Comment: your debugging efforts will be much easier if you run with `error_reporting = E_ALL`.  you're fumbling around in a complete darkness because *you* have turned the lights off.

Comment: Check you config file,  or provide config code without details.

Comment: try `echo "no of rows returned is : ".mysqli_num_rows($result);` and check whether query return a row or not

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_row does not return associated array.

Instead, Use mysqli_fetch_array

Also, check if your query is returning any record

Comment: Thank you it is working with mysqli_fetch_query , I want to assign the selected dropdown value to a variable, how can i do that?